# SQL subqueries or union

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, union

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and having troubles returning the rows the way I need it. The following query returns the following data.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    [DATE_PULL] as d, 
    [OWNER] as label, 
    SUM(VM_COUNT) as value 
FROM 
    [VCENTER_INFO_HIST] 
GROUP BY 
    OWNER, DATE_PULL
```

Resulting output:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|    D       |   label        |  value            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 06/30/2014 |    Test1       |       443         |
| 06/30/2014 |    Test2       |       456         |
| 06/30/2014 |    Test3       |       487         |
| 07/07/2014 |    Test1       |       1024        |
| 07/07/2014 |    Test2       |       2056        |
| 07/07/2014 |    Test3       |       2076        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    D       |   Test1        |      Test2        |      Test3        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 06/30/2014 |    443         |       456         |       487         | 
| 07/07/2014 |    1024        |       2056        |       2076        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are the values Test1, Test2 and Test3 constant?

Comment: Yes, Test1, Test2 & Test3 are constant, the dates are not.

Comment: Well that's pretty easy. Just use [pivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx).  If you ever need dynamic columns you can [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17772660/119477)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR label IN (Test1,Test2,Test3))pvt
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6759d/1/0)

With your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT [DATE_PULL] as d, [OWNER] as label, sum(VM_COUNT) as value 
      FROM [VCENTER_INFO_HIST] 
      GROUP BY OWNER, DATE_PULL
      )sub
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR label IN (Test1,Test2,Test3))pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `pivot`

```
SELECT * FROM [VCENTER_INFO_HIST]
pivot (sum(VM_COUNT) for OWNER in ([Test1], [Test2], [Test3])) as pvt
```